I have an issue with copying the report template of the pdf quote and use it in my custom module
I'm new to odoo and I have a little experience in modules development, I have an issue related to making the company stamp appear in the sales quote I made it appear there by enheriting the view and adding the stamp using my custom module and everything is working just fine, but the issue is that every quote will have the stamp on it so I decided to make a button on the view named "quote without stamp" so if I click on this specific button it will give me the invoice without stamp I did some research and I found out that the best solution is to copy the template of the invoice and paste it there and it will be printed without stamp normally, but it's not working ,I hope you could help or guide me.
this is the code and the error bellow:
The button able to generate pdf without stamp
the model.py file
from odoo import models
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

def print_without_stamp(self):
        return self.env.ref('md_stamp.action_report_saleorder_document_without_stamp').report_action(self)

the report.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_report_saleorder_document_without_stamp" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">Sales Order without Stamp</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">md_stamp.report_saleorder_document_without_stamp</field>
        <field name="report_file">md_stamp.report_saleorder_document_without_stamp</field>
        <field name="print_report_name">'Sales Order without Stamp - %s' % (object.name)</field>
    </record>
</odoo>   

the report_saleorder_document.xml (print with stamp xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_saleorder_document_inherit" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="inside">
            <!-- Add the stamp image here -->
            <div class="text-center mt-4">
                <img src="/web/static/img/cachet_transp_270x161.png" alt="Stamp" style="width:270px;"/>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>    

report_saleorder_document_without_stamp.xml (print without stamp, I copied the template from the sales report and pasted it here and changed the id)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_saleorder_document_without_stamp">
       <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context(lang=doc.partner_id.lang)" />
            <t t-set="forced_vat" t-value="doc.fiscal_position_id.foreign_vat"/>
            <t t-set="address">
                <div t-field="doc.partner_id"
                    t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' />
                <p t-if="doc.partner_id.vat">
                    <t t-if="doc.company_id.account_fiscal_country_id.vat_label" t-out="doc.company_id.account_fiscal_country_id.vat_label"/>
                    <t t-else="">Tax ID</t>: <span t-field="doc.partner_id.vat"/>
                </p>
            </t>
            <t t-if="doc.partner_shipping_id == doc.partner_invoice_id
                                 and doc.partner_invoice_id != doc.partner_id
                                 or doc.partner_shipping_id != doc.partner_invoice_id">
                <t t-set="information_block">
                    <strong>
                        <t t-if="doc.partner_shipping_id == doc.partner_invoice_id">
                            Invoicing and Shipping Address:
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            Invoicing Address:
                        </t>
                    </strong>
                    <div t-field="doc.partner_invoice_id"
                        t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
                    <t t-if="doc.partner_shipping_id != doc.partner_invoice_id">
                        <strong>Shipping Address:</strong>
                        <div t-field="doc.partner_shipping_id"
                            t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": True}'/>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
            <div class="page">
                <div class="oe_structure"/>

                <h2 class="mt-4">
                    <span t-if="env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma">Pro-Forma Invoice # </span>
                    <span t-elif="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">Quotation # </span>
                    <span t-else="">Order # </span>
                    <span t-field="doc.name">SO0000</span>
                </h2>

                <div class="row mt-4 mb-2" id="informations">
                    <div t-if="doc.client_order_ref" class="col-auto col-3 mw-100 mb-2" name="informations_reference">
                        <strong>Your Reference:</strong><br/>
                        <span class="m-0" t-field="doc.client_order_ref">SO0000</span>
                    </div>
                    <div t-if="doc.date_order" class="col-auto col-3 mw-100 mb-2" name="informations_date">
                        <strong t-if="doc.state in ['draft', 'sent']">Quotation Date:</strong>
                        <strong t-else="">Order Date:</strong><br/>
                        <span class="m-0" t-field="doc.date_order" t-options='{"widget": "date"}'>2023-12-31</span>
                    </div>
                    <div t-if="doc.validity_date and doc.state in ['draft', 'sent']"
                        class="col-auto col-3 mw-100 mb-2"
                        name="expiration_date">
                        <strong>Expiration:</strong><br/>
                        <span class="m-0" t-field="doc.validity_date">2023-12-31</span>
                    </div>
                    <div t-if="doc.user_id.name" class="col-auto col-3 mw-100 mb-2">
                        <strong>Salesperson:</strong><br/>
                        <span class="m-0" t-field="doc.user_id">Mitchell Admin</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Is there a discount on at least one line? -->
                <t t-set="lines_to_report" t-value="doc._get_order_lines_to_report()"/>
                <t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any(l.discount for l in lines_to_report)"/>

                <div class="oe_structure"></div>
                <table class="table table-sm o_main_table table-borderless mt-4">
                    <!-- In case we want to repeat the header, remove "display: table-row-group" -->
                    <thead style="display: table-row-group">
                        <tr>
                            <th name="th_description" class="text-start">Description</th>
                            <th name="th_quantity" class="text-end">Quantity</th>
                            <th name="th_priceunit" class="text-end">Unit Price</th>
                            <th name="th_discount" t-if="display_discount" class="text-end">
                                <span>Disc.%</span>
                            </th>
                            <th name="th_taxes" class="text-end">Taxes</th>
                            <th name="th_subtotal" class="text-end">
                                <span>Amount</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="sale_tbody">

                        <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>

                        <t t-foreach="lines_to_report" t-as="line">

                            <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_subtotal"/>

                            <tr t-att-class="'bg-200 fw-bold o_line_section' if line.display_type == 'line_section' else 'fst-italic o_line_note' if line.display_type == 'line_note' else ''">
                                <t t-if="not line.display_type">
                                    <td name="td_name"><span t-field="line.name">Bacon Burger</span></td>
                                    <td name="td_quantity" class="text-end">
                                        <span t-field="line.product_uom_qty">3</span>
                                        <span t-field="line.product_uom">units</span>
                                        <span t-if="line.product_packaging_id">
                                            (<span t-field="line.product_packaging_qty" t-options='{"widget": "integer"}'/> <span t-field="line.product_packaging_id"/>)
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td name="td_priceunit" class="text-end">
                                        <span t-field="line.price_unit">3</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-end">
                                        <span t-field="line.discount">-</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <t t-set="taxes" t-value="', '.join([(tax.invoice_label or tax.name) for tax in line.tax_id])"/>
                                    <td name="td_taxes" t-attf-class="text-end {{ 'text-nowrap' if len(taxes) &lt; 10 else '' }}">
                                        <span t-out="taxes">Tax 15%</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td t-if="not line.is_downpayment" name="td_subtotal" class="text-end o_price_total">
                                        <span t-field="line.price_subtotal">27.00</span>
                                    </td>
                                </t>
                                <t t-elif="line.display_type == 'line_section'">
                                    <td name="td_section_line" colspan="99">
                                        <span t-field="line.name">A section title</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <t t-set="current_section" t-value="line"/>
                                    <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>
                                </t>
                                <t t-elif="line.display_type == 'line_note'">
                                    <td name="td_note_line" colspan="99">
                                        <span t-field="line.name">A note, whose content usually applies to the section or product above.</span>
                                    </td>
                                </t>
                            </tr>

                            <t t-if="current_section and (line_last or lines_to_report[line_index+1].display_type == 'line_section') and not line.is_downpayment">
                                <tr class="is-subtotal text-end">
                                    <td name="td_section_subtotal" colspan="99">
                                        <strong class="mr16">Subtotal</strong>
                                        <span
                                            t-out="current_subtotal"
                                            t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": doc.currency_id}'
                                        >31.05</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </t>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clearfix" name="so_total_summary">
                    <div id="total" class="row" name="total">
                        <div t-attf-class="#{'col-6' if report_type != 'html' else 'col-sm-7 col-md-6'} ms-auto">
                            <table class="table table-sm table-borderless">
                                <!-- Tax totals -->
                                <t t-set="tax_totals" t-value="doc.tax_totals"/>
                                <t t-call="sale.document_tax_totals"/>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oe_structure"></div>

                <div t-if="not doc.signature" class="oe_structure"></div>
                <div t-else="" class="mt-4 ml64 mr4" name="signature">
                    <div class="offset-8">
                        <strong>Signature</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-8">
                        <img t-att-src="image_data_uri(doc.signature)" style="max-height: 4cm; max-width: 8cm;"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-8 text-center">
                        <span t-field="doc.signed_by">Oscar Morgan</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span t-field="doc.note" t-attf-style="#{'text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word;' if doc.company_id.terms_type != 'html' else ''}" name="order_note"/>
                    <p t-if="not is_html_empty(doc.payment_term_id.note)">
                        <span t-field="doc.payment_term_id.note">The payment should also be transmitted with love</span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="oe_structure"/>
                    <p t-if="doc.fiscal_position_id and not is_html_empty(doc.fiscal_position_id.sudo().note)"
                        id="fiscal_position_remark">
                        <strong>Fiscal Position Remark:</strong>
                        <span t-field="doc.fiscal_position_id.sudo().note">No further requirements for this payment</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="oe_structure"/>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>

the view.xml (the view of the print without stamp button)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <header>
                <button name="print_without_stamp" type="object" string="Print without Stamp" class="oe_highlight"/>
            </header>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

the manifest file
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "md_stamp",
    'summary': "Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose",
    'description': """
Long description of module's purpose
    """,
    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "https://www.yourcompany.com",
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',
    'depends': ['base', 'sale'],
    'data': [
        'views/report_saleorder_document.xml',
        'views/report_saleorder_document_without_stamp.xml',
        'views/report.xml',  # Include the report action definition
        'views/views.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}

now when I print the odoo default print pdf button it prints with stamp normally, but when I use my button "print without stamp" I get this error:
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<1825>", line 1358, in template_1825
  File "<1825>", line 1340, in template_1825_content
  File "<1825>", line 194, in template_1825_t_call_0
KeyError: 'doc'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\report.py", line 113, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter, context=context)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\http.py", line 741, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\report.py", line 42, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context)._render_qweb_pdf(reportname, docids, data=data)[0]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\account\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 61, in _render_qweb_pdf
    return super()._render_qweb_pdf(report_ref, res_ids=res_ids, data=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 899, in _render_qweb_pdf
    collected_streams = self._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\sale_pdf_quote_builder\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 17, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    result = super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\account\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 20, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    return super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 749, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    html = self.with_context(**additional_context)._render_qweb_html(report_ref, all_res_ids_wo_stream, data=data)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 949, in _render_qweb_html
    return self._render_template(report.report_name, data), 'html'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions_report.py", line 669, in _render_template
    return view_obj._render_template(template, values).encode()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 2051, in _render_template
    return self.env['ir.qweb']._render(template, values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\tools\profiler.py", line 292, in _tracked_method_render
    return method_render(self, template, values, **options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240729\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_qweb.py", line 599, in _render
    result = ''.join(rendering)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<1825>", line 1364, in template_1825
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_qweb.QWebException: Error while render the template
KeyError: 'doc'
Template: md_stamp.report_saleorder_document_without_stamp
Path: /t/t/t[2]
Node: <t t-set="forced_vat" t-value="doc.fiscal_position_id.foreign_vat"/>

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    RPC_ERROR
        at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/ffa11b5/web.assets_web.min.js:2886:163)
        at decoder.onload (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/ffa11b5/web.assets_web.min.js:2872:7)

Make the button "print without stamp" function correctly using my custom module

The error suggests that "doc" is required in line 5 but is not defined in report_saleorder_document_without_stamp template. For some reason the error did not occur in line 4 but if you notice line 4 does a t-set="doc" but requires a pre-existing "doc" variable.
If you take a look at Odoo's "sale" addon, you'll see that their action_report_sale order calls the report_saleorder template (around line 189), which loops through "docs" to set a "doc" variable on each iteration and only then is report_saleorder_document template called. The template you copied should just be missing this step.
<!-- addons/sale/report/ir_actions_report_templates.xml:line 189 -->
<template id="report_saleorder_raw">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="sale.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

To add on, if you intend to copy a template wholesale, you can consider calling the original template directly in report.xml in the "report_name" field.
Alternatively, you can do a <t t-call="sale.report_saleorder_document" /> rather than explicitly copying everything over. This way, in the future when the "sale" addon updates, you don't have to copy everything over again.

If I call it in the report.xml what shall I put in the report_saleorder_document_without_stamp.xml? Or I won't need it since I have no modifications (it's without stamp)

For report_saleorder_document_without_stamp.xml, you would really just need to copy the  block above, then replace the t-call with whatever template you copied from in your original code.
